# HTML5 input type radio returns value to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button

Recently I have noticed that I can directly reference the value of an input radio button. For example, I have the following HTML

```
<form name="test">
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="yellow">Yellow<br>
</form>
```

Now in Javascript, I am able to get the value of the radio button without having to step through each radio button or use an onclick function. I can successfully issue the following statement:

```
var userColor = document.test.colors.value;
```

userColor will return red, blue or yellow based on the currently selected radio button.

Why does this now work? I have tested in Firefox, Chrome & IE.

And I have seen on some other devices this does not work. Why causes the variation? Is it something to do with the prototype used to create the input element?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not implemented equals in all browsers.
This functionality may be introduced with the las updates, and then the older browser version or the less powerful browser don't support it.

I don't know if this is a new functionality, but here (http://caniuse.com) you could find all the new JS feature and all browsers supporting.

Comment: It is the strangest thing - I can't seem to find out why I can directly address the value of a radio button! Thanks for your suggestions but still would like an answer as to why.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using ***<select>*** instead of  ***radio button***

HTML:

```
<form name="test">
 <select id="colorSelector">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
 </select>
<input type="button" onclick="changeColor()" value="Change color"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeColor() {
 var redColor = "red";
 var blueColor = "blue";
 var yellowColor = "yellow";
 var selectedColor = document.getElementById("colorSelector").value;

if(selectedColor==redColor)
{
 //some codes
}
else if(selectedColor== blueColor)
{
 //some codes
}
else if(selectedColor==yellowColor)
{
 //some codes
}
else
{
 //some codes
}

}
```

Please apologize if anything is wrong.

Comment: I know how in the past we have been told to implement radio buttons. My point is that recently I have realized I can directly address radio buttons and do not need to make my code so complicated. But why the change?

Comment: So what's really your question?

Comment: I was never able to directly address a radio button value before but now I can. There are many posts about how to get around the fact that you cannot directly address a radio button (so people use things like select instead or loops to determine the selected radio button). However, I am able to write an app now that allows direct address to a input type="radio" just like we have always addressed an input type="text".